# Sum of the values of an arbitrary multidimensional function?

Tags: python, function, sum

Suppose we have a variable sets [image: $V={v_1,v_2,...,v_n}$] and suppose each variable gets few values from sets [image: W_i]. So [image: $v_i \in W_i$]. Now there is a function [image: $f(v_1,...,v_n)$]. How can I sum up on all possible values of [image: $v_1$] to [image: $v_n$] on [image: $f$]?

For example if [image: $V={v_1,v_2}$] and [image: $v_1 \in {1,2}$] and [image: $v_2 \in {3,4,5}$] and [image: $f(v_1,v_2)=v_1.v_2$] then I am looking for:

[image: $$\sum\limits_{v_1\in {1,2}}{\sum\limits_{v_2 \in {3,4,5}}{f(v_1,v_2)}}=f(1,3)+f(1,4)+f(1,5)+f(2,3)+f(2,4)+f(2,5)$$]

*The size of [image: $V$] can change. So the size of it is also changing. I didn't want to write in a complex form but actually I am adding up multiple functions which each has their own variable set.

Comment: I think the syntax you're trying to use only works in `mathematica.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that would be unbelievable if a computer programming language cannot cover this! Its vital in some cases!

Comment: @Naji I tried image substitutes

Comment: @Nile thanks a lot but why it is so non-relative to the size of the font? Why other stackexchange subdomains like tex.stackexchange.com and math.stackexchange.com don't have this problem?

Comment: @Naji They have a system that converts them... for the above, I just used a text to image converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> V = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
>>> summ = 0
>>> for x in product(*V):
    print x
    # or call some function : summ += func(*x)
...     
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to represent the sets.  So V is a list of lists.

```
V = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
r = [[]]
for v in V:
    r = [ i + [y] for y in v for i in r ]

# at this point, r contains the inputs for your functions
sum = 0
for domain in r:
    sum += function(domain)
```

All you have to do is define your function to accept a list.  In your example, it would be this:

```
def function(l):
    return l[0] * l[1]
```

Comment: This would only work if you already know have many elements are in V and therefore you will need only two loops to iterate everything. In my case that can change.

Comment: Have you tried with multiple elements in V?  This will work with arbitrary number of V...